# API Explorer shows only public Google Services

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

just updated to GAE 1.7.7 and since then the API Explorer doesn't show my API Services anymore, but only all public Google API Services. I generated the discovery document, cleared the browser cache, but the GAE logs keeps telling "GET /_ah/api/explorer HTTP/1.1" 302

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it has been a temporary bug of GAE, but now it's working fine again. It lasted some hours and it drove me a little crazy as well...